# Can you search through variables in Kate editor

Tags: kate

I was writing a C program in Kate and I had to modify a few lines with a variable called 'wheel'. So I used the default search functions of Kate.

The problem I was having, was that the same name 'wheel' also existed in the comments. So I could not effectively search through all lines in which 'wheel' was used as variable.

Does kate have the feature that you can search for a specific variable in your code? If so how is it called?

Comment: Pretty sure there is no way to exclude matches in comments. Best option is probably to use grep and a fancy regex. discussion here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33131/how-to-grep-on-source-code-without-catching-comments

Answer (score 0):

A Kate developer here: Kate does not have any code model or other syntactic representation of your text. You can use the action Ctrl+H, which first selects the word under the cursor, and when pressing Ctrl+H again, will jump to the next case sensitive match. But there is no option to omit comments for instance.